# Disable "Package Installation" dialogue on MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, installing

I wish to provide a setup script to my colleagues which sets up a working MiKTeX environment. Installation is done in 'basic' mode without admin privileges -- so far using the registry:

```
miktexsetup --local-package-repository=\\mymirror\miktex --package-set=basic install --modify-path --shared=no --verbose --use-registry
mpm --verbose --repository=\\mymirror\miktex --update
initexmf --enable-installer --updatefndb
```

Works, but the first call to pdflatex opens the "Package Installation" dialogue, asking me where to install from (I thought I already defined that with `--local-package-repository`) for whom (despite `--shared=no`) and if it should ask me again for the next package (despite `--enable-installer`).

How can I disable this annoying dialogue? If my colleagues are given any chance to goof it, somebody will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the configuration value `[MPM]AutoInstall` (documented [here](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex.ini.html)):

```
initexmf --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=t
```

Or, if you want to disable the auto-installer:

```
initexmf --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=f
```

To get back the annoying dialog:

```
initexmf --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=?
```

Comment: Works for me, but is weird. According to the initexmf documentation, `initexmf --enable-installer` should do the same and "overrules settings in the MiKTeX configuration data store".

Comment: `--enable-installer` does not modify the MiKTeX configuration data store. It just enables auto-installation for the current program invocation.